# SQL injection attempt - is my code vulnerable?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I found in my logs that someone is trying to attack my page. I have some sub-pages where data is pulled from an DB via an ID that is submitted by the URL. Like page.php?id=666
What I could find in my logs are these attacks:

```
page.php?id=../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
page.php?id=/proc/self/environ
page.php?id=-1%27
```

And even more important, is my code weak? Might this attack have been successful?

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT *
    FROM mytable AS myvar
    WHERE myvar.ID =:ID");
    $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That `../../../etc/passwd` isn't a SQL injection attack, but rather it's a directory traversal attack attempting to read arbitrary files on your server filesystem.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem vulnerable to SQL Injection since you are using parametrized queries already.

Comment: Your PDO prepared statement isn't vulnerable to SQL injection, it's safe.  If you have other code which reads files based on user input from `$_GET,$_POST,$_COOKIE` or any other mechanism, you would need to filter it against breaking out of the intended read location.

Comment: The second request, `page.php?id=/proc/self/environ`, is also aimed to identify local file read/inclusion vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Seems that I am save. The page is hosted on a webhotel. Hopefully the admins keep the etc/passwd directory save as I guess this is nothing I have access to on a shared hoster?!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this code is not vulnerable to SQL injections.

Both the `intval` conversion and prepared statement with `PDO::PARAM_INT` binding ensure that only integer values are used in the comparison of the statement that is being executed.

Anyways, the mentioned requests don’t seem to aim for identifying SQL injections only but several different vulnerabilities, e. g., [Path Traversal (CWE-22)](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/22.html) and [Local File Inclusion (CWE-98)](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/98.html) as well. So you may want to watch out for those vulnerabilities as well.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the attacker tried to access documents and other data in various directories on your web server. I don't think it's SQL Injection. However, make sure you are protecting access to directories and all documents wherever necessary.

You're on PDO with prepared statements, that should keep you safe from injection.

Comment: It's not just PDO, but using parametrized queries in PDO, that is keeping OP safe.  It's possible to write code that's vulnerable to SQL injection using PDO if you build SQL statements with outside data.  I know you know this, but for the benefit of others who might not realize it: Simply using PDO does not keep you safe.

Comment: @AndyLester Yup, I corrected it. that's right. I just forgot to mention prepared statements.